# PHP stmt bindParam simple error that I cant spot

Tags: php, mysql

```
        <?php
        include_once('dbcon.php');
            if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                $stmt =$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,email,phone) VALUES (:name,:email,:phone)");
                $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
                $stmt->execute();
        }

    ?>
```

This is my code it's super simple the database works and all but I was trying to add another table that didn't work to it and it flopped and I messed something up on line 11 I think, any help would be extremely appreciated, thanks in advance !

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in E:\utsdata\2T\2809984199\GsoVerk4\register.php:11 Stack trace: #0 E:\utsdata\2T\2809984199\GsoVerk4\register.php(11): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in E:\utsdata\2T\2809984199\GsoVerk4\register.php on line 11

---

This is the error that I get

Comment: Whats your table structure?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/cbf2ff6e402098168f3b47b39651c102 It looks like this, keep in mind that I am only using users as of now.

Comment: Then @syck is almost certainly correct - your primary key (id) should be set to autoincrement

Comment: Alright Ill try that if thats the problem it's super weird because the code worked about an hour ago with the same table and the same code. Ill come back to you with a result.

Comment: It worked thanks for the help, this was a very simple error to spot it just make sense to me because it was working before with the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you forgot to make your `PRIMARY KEY` column `autoincrement`-ing

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to mention that  the code worked 100% before I tried to add other table, so Im pretty confident that it's not an error with the Dbcon or Sql side of the project.

Comment: Check the other tables too for missing autoincrement attributes.